# HTML & CSS Line up right aligned elements inside and outside of a (sometimes) scrollable div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

i have a legend for a graph that sometimes is scrollable and sometimes isn't.

Unfortunately when the scrollbar shows up, it pushes all of the elements over to the left a bit. So they don't line up with a total (outside the scrollable area)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3sKVR/

A simple answer would be to just set a fixed width, but unfortunately, it has to be responsive.

Also, i can't use custom scrollbars to maintain consistency with the rest of the site and also bring down page-load times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (with internet points!)

Cut down version of code:

HTML:

```
<div id="legend_cont">
    <div id="legend_list">
        <div id="legend">
            <div class="legend_row">
                <div class="legend_cell">
                    <div class="legend_colour" style="background-color:#ffb100"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="legend_cell">Merch G</div>
                <div class="legend_cell legend_value">$1423.24</div>
            </div>
            <div class="legend_row">
                <div class="legend_cell">
                    <div class="legend_colour" style="background-color:#ed5929"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="legend_cell">Merch L</div>
                <div class="legend_cell legend_value">$1351.07</div>
            </div>
            <div class="legend_row">
                <div class="legend_cell">
                    <div class="legend_colour" style="background-color:#3f9c35"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="legend_cell">Merch N</div>
                <div class="legend_cell legend_value">$1194.90</div>
            </div>
            <div class="legend_row">
                <div class="legend_cell">
                    <div class="legend_colour" style="background-color:#009bbb"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="legend_cell">Merch T</div>
                <div class="legend_cell legend_value">$1188.14</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="legend_total">Total:<span id="legend_total_value">$0.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#legend_cont {
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 2px solid #ADADAD;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}
#legend_list {
    height: 169px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 20px 4% 20px 7%;
}
#legend {
    display: table;
    width: 90%;
}
.legend_row {
    display: table-row;
}
.legend_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.legend_colour {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.legend_value {
    text-align: right;
}
#legend_total {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 88%;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    margin-left: 8%;
}
#legend_total_value {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: can you use nicescroll? http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: it might be scrollbar width.. you could use custom scrollbar on mouse over

Comment: I'd really prefer to not use any custom scrollbars as i need to maintain consistency with the rest of the site. I'll add this info to my question.

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure there is always a scroll bar

**CSS**

```
#legend_cont {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

2) Use js to grab the variable width of the scrollbar ([example here](http://www.fleegix.org/articles/2006/05/30/getting-the-scrollbar-width-in-pixels))

3) Set the padding-right in #legend_total_value equal to that variable in jquery.

**JS**

```
$('#legend_total_value').css('padding-right', wScroll);​
```

Comment: Using my powers of deduction, i know that you are using a Mac @Doa! Unfortunately on windows, width 100% only takes up 100% of the space left after the scrollbar.

Comment: Ha and thanks for the height tweak. All my font styles are on the body of the page, so i'm not cutting anything in the real one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `padding-right` to compensate for the size of scrollbar when it's not there and position the total accordingly.

```
#legend_list {
 height: 169px;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 20px 4% 20px 7%;
 padding-right:15px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3sKVR/16/)

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately this makes an assumption of the width of a browser's scrollbar. Again, close but no cigar (i'm still trying loads of alternatives myself!)

Comment: @RykWaters yes, unfortunately different browsers provide different scrollbars… you've to either consider an average size or, *custome scrollbar* i guess...

Comment: Hey @Tilwin Joy, seems that we can get the scrollbar width via JS and then sort all the padding from there. Thanks for the help